# Wi-Fi access point with login page

Tags: login, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration, dnsmasq

Currently I'm using hostapd and dnsmasq. And I want to add something like login page: user connects to ap, opens any site and my wifi/dns-program automatically redirects him to the login page till he didn't enter correct credentials. I've found something on the raymond.cc but it's only for windows. So what should I use?

And I also want few sites to be available even before log-in

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a Captive Portal, this should do the trick:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/CoovaChilli

Comment: And what about whitelist sites?